# Correct way to use multiple item in the ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is a part of my question which I deleted because its too broad
I created a ActionLink for my blog Archive but I'm having trouble with it because I'm calling multiple items inside it.
This is my codes which return an error message **No overload for method ActionLink takes 7 arguments**

```
@model IEnumerable <Project.Models.ArchiveListModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<br />
@Html.ActionLink(item.AchiveMonth, item.AchiveYear, item.PostCount, "ArchiveBrowse", "Post", 
new { AchiveYear =  item.AchiveMonth, ArchiveMonth = item.AchiveYear, PostCount = item.PostCount }, null) 

}
```

This is my original codes but doesn't have a link it only gives a list

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<br />
<li> @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item.AchiveMonth) @item.AchiveYear (@item.PostCount) </li>   
} 
</fieldset><br/>
```

output:

```
January 2013 (1)
February 2013 (1)
December 2012 (4)
```

Here's how I do it in my controller but I know its not working. T_T

```
 public ActionResult Archive()
        {
            var archivelst = repository.AchiveList().ToList();
            return View(archivelst);
        }

  //this one below is not working
  public ActionResult ArchiveBrowse(string archive)
    {
        var achivemodel = db.Posts.Include("Posts").Single(a => a.Title == archive);
        return View(achivemodel);
    }
            return View(achivemodel);
```

My ArchiveRepository

```
 public IQueryable<ArchiveListModel> AchiveList()
        {

            var ac = from Post in db.Posts
                     group Post by new { Post.DateTime.Year, Post.DateTime.Month }
                     into dategroup
                     select new ArchiveListModel()
                      {

                         AchiveYear = dategroup.Key.Year,
                         AchiveMonth = dategroup.Key.Month,
                         PostCount = dategroup.Count()

                       };

            return ac;
        }
```

What's the correct way to call multiple items in the view?

What I'm trying here is to view the list of Posts under a specific month and year or something like Blog Archives. 
**Latest Update(working)**
Finally I was able to make it work this is now a working one
**Updated ArchiveRepository**

```
 public IQueryable<ArchiveListModel> AchiveList()
        {

            var ac = from Post in db.Posts
                     group Post by new { Post.DateTime.Year, Post.DateTime.Month }
                     into dategroup
                     select new ArchiveListModel()
                      {

                         AchiveYear = dategroup.Key.Year,
                         AchiveMonth = dategroup.Key.Month,
                         PostCount = dategroup.Count()

                       };

            return ac;
        }
```

**Updated Controller**

```
public ActionResult ArchiveBrowse(int AchiveYear, int AchiveMonth, int PostCount)
        {
            var archivemodel = (from a in db.Posts
                                where a.DateTime.Year == AchiveYear &&
                                      a.DateTime.Month == AchiveMonth
                                select a).ToList();


            return View(archivemodel);
        }
```

**Updated View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
@Html.ActionLink(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item.AchiveMonth) + "" + item.AchiveYear + " (" + item.PostCount + ")",
  "ArchiveBrowse", "Post", new
  {
      AchiveYear = item.AchiveYear,
      AchiveMonth = item.AchiveMonth,
      PostCount = item.PostCount
  }, null) 

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "calling" multiple items? You can have `Html.ActionLink(item.AchiveMonth, "Archive", "Item", new { AchiveYear =  item.AchiveMonth, ArchiveMonth = item.AchiveYear, PostCount = item.PostCount }, null)` then in your controller, just have AchiveYear, ArchiveMonth, PostCount as parameters.

Comment: sorry what I'm pointing there is the three items. The ArchiveYear, ArchiveMonth and PostCount.. :D I updated my question for you to understand better. I know it can be done using your suggestion but I dont know how to do it. :( could you please help me correct my codes above? thanks..

Comment: You should use only one link text for ActionLink.

Comment: nice suggestion.. I'll try to think about it..

Comment: I still having a hard time doing it.. T_T

Comment: Basically, make the first three parameters in your first code snippet into one.  You can concatenate the strings together to join them, but only the first parameter is the actual text.  The next two should be the action method and controller to invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not clear to me when you said "call multiple items" so here's my answer, assuming you want to make the list of `months years (postcount)` into a link. To get this output below

```
January 2013 (1)
February 2013 (1)
December 2012 (4)
```

you can concatenate the strings `item.AchiveMonth`, `item.AchiveYear` and `item.PostCount`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.AchiveMonth + " " + item.AchiveYear + " ("+ item.PostCount + ")",
"ArchiveBrowse", 
"Post", 
    new { 
          AchiveYear =  item.AchiveYear, 
          ArchiveMonth = item.AchiveMonth, 
          PostCount = item.PostCount },
 null)
```

then in `ArchiveBrowse`, make sure that your parameters line up properly:

```
public ActionResult ArchiveBrowse(string AchiveYear, string ArchiveMonth, string PostCount)
{
     //Not sure if you want to display posts in the clicked month/year
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping dude. As of now I will mark your suggestion as the answer but I still have to test it :). Yeah, I want to display posts in the clicked month/year. I tried but I have a hard time doing it because the month/year is inside the posts table T_T. Sorry I'm not that good in querying. I would greatly appreciate if you would me. Thanks.